# PowerBI Enhanced Meta Data Query Overhead

Tags: optimization, powerbi

It appears that Enhanced Meta Data queries are causing a ton of load/overhead on our SQL database. It's very heavy and seems to be running all day long.  We've done quite a bit of research and can't seem to figure out how to turn it off.  We've removed direct query from almost all of our reports so far.  We really need to eliminate this overhead.

Query below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
select t.[TABLE_CATALOG], t.[TABLE_SCHEMA], t.[TABLE_NAME], t.[TABLE_TYPE], tv.create_date [CREATED_DATE], tv.modify_date [MODIFIED_DATE], cast(e.value as nvarchar(max)) [DESCRIPTION]
from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] t
join sys.schemas s on s.name = t.[TABLE_SCHEMA]
join sys.objects tv on tv.name = t.[TABLE_NAME] and tv.schema_id = s.schema_id and tv.parent_object_id = 0
left outer join (select null major_id, null minor_id, null class, null name, null value) e on tv.object_id = e.major_id and e.minor_id = 0 and e.class = 1 and e.name = 'MS_Description'
where 1=1 and 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

For import models you can suppress the metadata queries by using a Native SQL Query to start Power Query instead of navigating to the target table. EG:

```
Value.NativeQuery(Source, "select * from SomeTable", null, [EnableFolding = true])
```

[Query folding on native queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/native-query-folding)